# Unable to install gem

Tags: ruby

I am getting this error, when trying to install any gem
ERROR:  http://gems.rubyforge.org/ does not appear to be a repository
But when I do gem sources, it shows
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***
http://gems.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you have an http proxy in your network? What do you see when you go to the page http://gems.rubyforge.org/ directly (using your browser)? Or even better: what happens if you wget the url 'http://gems.rubyforge.org/yaml'?

Comment: i am having this problem on starbucks right now, i just opened the URL with my browser, and its like the firewall its allowing me to acces it using Gems now.

Comment: strange, this stuff probably is different from site to site.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to [update rubygems](http://rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page14).